# what's the relationship between checkpoint and commit for transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions

my textbook says:

***A checkpoint is a periodic operation that forces all dirty pages for the database currently in use to be written to disk***

I am very confused. I know how cache works bur what are dirty pages in regards to? if dirty pages are written to disk, isn't that what a commit supposed to do? how come it is checkpoints that actually 'commit' data to physical pages?

Let's say we have the following code;

```
BEGIN TRAN T1;  
UPDATE table1 
SET postcode = '9000'  //was 8000 before
WHERE CustomerID = 1;
COMMIT TRAN T1;
```

Here is sth I don't understand, the record(CustomerID = 1 with postcode 8000) is read into cache first, then update statement make the record in cache dirty pages(because we changed the postcode), now a checkpoint happens, then this record is written to mdf/ndf, isn't that like a commit whose purpose is to make changes permanent in database? and there is no log file involved?

Could anyone take this example to guide me what actually happen and how the new postcode 9000 get written to database permanently?

Comment: Transactions commit by synchronously writing to the transaction log, which always happens before any data is written. Data is committed by asynchronously writing dirty pages as dictated per checkpoints. This is possible because, if a crash happens and the data is lost, it can be regenerated by replaying the transaction log. If you use delayed durability (a new feature of SQL Server 2014) even the transaction log writes can be delayed somewhat, at a cost of reduced reliability.

Comment: @JeroenMostert   when you say  'Data is committed by asynchronously writing dirty pages as dictated per checkpoints', does it mean that a checkpoint needs to analyze the log file to know which changes should be made permanently in database?

Comment: No -- it only needs to run past the list of dirty pages in the buffer pool (cache). This is entirely separate from the transaction log. By definition, *all* changes should be made permanent in the database, it's just a matter of when. Analyzing the t'log only becomes necessary on startup/recovery. (A rollback is a little more complicated; things are optimized for transactions being committed. I don't know off the top of my head how rollbacks and checkpoints interact, but it likely involves writing data twice.)

Comment: Ah, here's a [question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/75821/97345) with a lot of juicy detail.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  So let me rephrase the question with steps: S1:I update a record, then commit it. S2: the updated record is in cache . S3: The commit flushes the updated record to the log file, the updated record hasn't been in real physical pages, so if other users try to query this record, they see old value or wait for my lock to be released. S4: A checkpoint occurs.                  
As you say a checkpoint doesn't check the log file, so how will the updated record be written to physical pages to make changes permanently. Who will do this job?

Comment: Your S3 is wrong: when you have committed the transaction in S1, the new data is visible. New queries will see the new values, as they read the new data page (which is in memory -- they are not required to go to disk, which is a good thing from a performance standpoint indeed). The checkpoint is the process that ensures the change is recorded on disk (and records in the t'log that this has happened and the page can be considered reliable when read back -- crucially this is per page, not per row). But really, check the linked question for the precise steps in the process, including latches.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  I will check the link. But  this is quoted  from my textbook:  "What you’re doing is visible to you only, and isn’t really done until you COMMIT — although it looks real to you. After you execute the UPDATE statement, you can still query the database as if your change was complete, but only you can see that result. Anyone else attempting to look will get results based on their TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL-they could have to wait for your lock to be released, they could see the old value, or if they’re daring they could get a dirty read." so the new data is invisible for others?

Comment: *Before* you commit, yes -- if someone uses `READ UNCOMMITTED`, they will see the dirty data; otherwise their statement will get blocked on a row lock. (Ignoring more advanced stuff like snapshot isolation, where there's multiple copies of the data and readers aren't blocked.) This is orthogonal to what the engine does with actually writing the data back, though. Things like `REPEATABLE READ` issue their own locks, to ensure *you* can't change the data for a transaction that expects an already read value not to change.